# Vue-router. Error in the browser console after using "npm update" command. Error: Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: npm, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Before updating project was working.

After updating with "npm update" command, browser console shows:

> Error: Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   open
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\beauty\node_modules\vue-router\dist\vue-router.esm.js'

In my bootstap file I add Vue-router like thiss

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
window.Vue.use(VueRouter);
```

I don't understand  where is problem and what should i do?

Comment: the problem disappeared without any actions in 5 - 10 min after I  discover it. I don't know what was that.

Comment: Sounds like an npm cache issue of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to *restart the dev server* since I've switched to a branch that had TypeScript introduced while started dev server on another (feature branch) that added vue-router but didn't have TS. I've merged and was puzzled why I got this error until I've realised that dev server probably doesn't recognize TS at all (depending on switching main.js to .ts and back I had the same or different error).